# adding a span to all the numbers in the body tag of the website using javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to add span tag with the specific class to all the numbers in my website using JavaScript. However I got the following:

```
  <script>
  var regex = /(\d+)/,
   replacement = '<span class="font-arial">$1</span>';
   function replaceText(el) {
   if (el.nodeType === 3) {
   if (regex.test(el.data)) {
   var temp_div = document.createElement('div');

   temp_div.innerHTML = el.data.replace(regex, replacement);
   var nodes = temp_div.childNodes;
   while (nodes[0]) {
       el.parentNode.insertBefore(nodes[0],el);
   }
   el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
  }
  } else if (el.nodeType === 1) {
  for (var i = 0; i < el.childNodes.length; i++) {
   replaceText(el.childNodes[i]);
   }
  }
 }
 replaceText(document.body);
</script>
```

But the problem is as below example:

If the number is: 45 7320272536

It put like this:

```
 <span class="arial">
 <span class="arial">45</span>
 </span>
  <span class="arial">
  <span class="arial">7320272536</span>
  </span>
```

I want like this:

```
  <span class="arial">45</span>
  <span class="arial">7320272536</span>
```

Comment: You seem to have all the code... its just a question of debugging. You could just use Chrome dev tools (by pressing F12) and just debug your code.

Comment: I tired to debug but no luck.. i m new to this plz help me out

Answer (score 1):

It can be simpler. You don't need to loop over child nodes one more time. Instead you can replace all number occurrences at once if you use [global match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) flag `g` for regexp object:

```
/(\d+)/g
```

So after cleaning the code with [`replaceChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.replaceChild) method, your code becomes:

```
var regex = /(\d+)/g,
    replacement = '<span class="font-arial">$1</span>';

function replaceText(el) {
    if (el.nodeType === 3) {
        if (regex.test(el.data)) {
            var temp_div = document.createElement('div');
            temp_div.innerHTML = el.data.replace(regex, replacement);
            el.parentNode.replaceChild(temp_div, el);
        }
    } else if (el.nodeType === 1) {
        for (var i = 0; i < el.childNodes.length; i++) {
            replaceText(el.childNodes[i]);
        }
    }
}

replaceText(document.body);
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/a09vac2t/

Comment: if number is +(0)237 773 1199: it gives 44
(
0
)
237
733
1199

Comment: no luck it is spliting up the line i want text to be retained in the same way

Comment: it works fine in http://jsfiddle.net/a09vac2t/ i tried changing content when i try that code in my site its splitting the lines

Comment: Try to set up a demo with this issue.

Comment: Changing "div" to "span" in createElement resolved the issue thanks a lot... :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working sample.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>replace test</title>
 <script>
    var regex = /(\d+)/;
    replacement = '<span style="border:1px solid red">$1</span>';
    function replaceText(el) {
        //alert('Testing: ' + el.data);
        //alert('Node type: ' + el.nodeType);
        if (el.nodeType === 3) {
            if (regex.test(el.data)) {
                //alert('Matches');
                var temp_div = document.createElement('div');

                temp_div.innerHTML = el.data.replace(regex, replacement);
                //alert('Making it ' + temp_div.innerHTML);
                var nodes = temp_div.childNodes;
                while (nodes[0]) {
                    //alert(nodes.length + ": " + nodes[0].data);
                    el.parentNode.insertBefore(nodes[0],el);
                }
                el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
            }
        } else if (el.nodeType === 1) {
            //alert('Looping children: ' + el.childNodes.length);
            var rootChildrenCopy = toArray(el.childNodes).slice(0);
            for (var i = 0; i < rootChildrenCopy.length; i++) {
                replaceText(rootChildrenCopy[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    function toArray(obj) {
        var array = [];
        // iterate backwards ensuring that length is an UInt32
        for (var i = obj.length >>> 0; i--;) { 
            array[i] = obj[i];
        }
        return array;
    }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="replaceText(document.getElementById('abc'))">
<p>This is a number</p>
<div id='abc'>Here is a 45 num</div>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: <span class="font-arial">
<span class="font-arial">
<span class="font-arial">
<span class="font-arial">
<span class="font-arial">0</span>
</span>
</span>
</span>
</span> its adding up so many span tags for each numbers

Answer (score 0):

Element.childNodes will change when you insert nodes, so you need to save a copy of it when looping. [Array.prototype.slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) is good for this.

In addition, you need to change your regex to replace all occurrences instead of just the first with the [global flag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp).